# Upgraded SearchKick and OpenSearch and can't get result type

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, searchkick

I've upgraded to Opensearch and upgraded Searchkick but this bit of my code now falls over:

```
  <% if @results %>
    <div class="search-results-wrapper search-results-wrapper--publications">
      <% if @results_count.to_i > 0 %>
        <h2><%= params[:order] == 'alphabetical' ? 'Alphabetical' : 'Relevance' %> Results:</h2>
        <%= page_entries_info @results unless @do_quick_search %>
        <%= paginate @results %>
        <% @results.each do |result| %>
          <% result_type = result._type.underscore %>
          <%= render partial: result_type, locals: { result: result } %>
        <% end %>
        <%= paginate @results %>
```

It should use the type of each result to render a specific partial. but it says:

> undefined method `underscore' for nil:NilClass

Looks like `_type` is no longer available?

Is there an alternative method I can use here?

@ankane